# No administrator privileges after creating O365 group with Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We're creating an O365 Group with the use of the Graph API.

When creating the O365 Group the corresponding SharePoint Site of this group is not initially created. We use a call to the Graph API to the group's Drive to initiate the creating of the SharePoint site.

After that there are no Site Administrators on the Group's SharePoint site. We can see that the Owners SharePoint group is created on the Group's Site. The Owners Active Directory group is also added to this Owners SharePoint group, but when we check the IsSiteAdmin property of the user which created the group (which is placed in the Owners Active Directory group) it is still false.

After some time, from 30 minutes to 24 hours and even longer, the Site Administrator permissions are available.

We've also used the Exchange API but that has the same issue. The only difference we can see is that the groups created with the Exchange API are visible from within Teams to promote it to a Team. The groups created with the Graph API are not visible at all from the Teams app, untill the Administrator permissions are available.

Is there a way to avoid these issues? Creating the group from SP UI is creating the site immediately and applies the Administrator permissions (almost) instantly.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: 
As a temporary workaround we managed to create the O365 group through a call to the _api/GroupSiteManager/CreateGroupEx API (the same one the new 'create site and group' functionality uses). In that case the group, site and admin privileges are directly (15 sec.) created.

Answer (score 0):

We noticed something similar regarding MS Teams. We created groups based on file shares and we only added users to the owner property and not also to the members list. Adding the admin also to the member resulted in getting the desired permission and solved the problem. The accounts could then add the MS Teams functions. If SharePoint is evaluating the the group membership and you only added the people to the owner property this makes sense because admins are not actually member of the group.